# While loops in ondraw

Tags: android, while-loop, ondraw

In my on draw its is made like a game. a zombie comes by and you have to click on him so it will go back to the start and not make it to you house. But I wanted to add a pause to my game so I though I will just wrap it all in a while loop... well when I tried this when the app opens it just opens with a black screen. here is some of my code.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas); 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(speed);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    text.setTextSize(50);
    white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    NightGreen.setColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
    DayGreen.setColor(Color.parseColor("#339900"));
    clear.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    grass.set(0, canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    AndroidDudeHitbox.set((int) AndroidX, (int) AndroidY, (int) AndroidX + AndroidDude.getWidth(),(int)  AndroidY + AndroidDude.getHeight());
    DoorHitbox.set(canvas.getWidth()/2 + 360, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300 + house.getWidth() - 10, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight() + house.getHeight());
    ZombieHitbox.set((int) ZombieX, (int) ZombieY, (int) ZombieX + Zombie.getWidth(), (int) ZombieY + Zombie.getHeight());
    PlayPauseHitbox.set(0, canvas.getHeight() - pause.getHeight(), pause.getWidth(), 25);

    while (PausePlay)
    {


        switch ((int) possition)
        {
        case 0:
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
            canvas.drawBitmap(sun, (int) SunX, (int) SunY, null);
            canvas.drawRect(grass, DayGreen);
            canvas.drawBitmap(house, canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight(), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(AndroidDude, (int) AndroidX - (AndroidDude.getWidth()/2), (int) AndroidY - (AndroidDude.getHeight()/2), null);
            text.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            if (counter < 300) canvas.drawText("QUICK! Get in your hous before Nightfall!", 160, canvas.getHeight()/2 + 100, text);
            text.setColor(Color.RED);

            //Log.d("Counter", "C: Counted " + counter);

            if (counter < 110) {SunY --; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 110 && counter < 240) {SunY --; SunX ++; counter++;} 
            if (counter >= 240 && counter < 360) {SunY -= 0.5; SunX ++; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 360 && counter < 662) {SunY -= 0.333; SunX ++; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 662 && counter < 1004) {SunY += 0.333; SunX++; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 1004 && counter < 1104) {SunY += 0.5; SunX++; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 1104 && counter < 1224) {SunY ++; SunX++; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 1224 && counter < 1345) {SunY ++; counter++;}
            if (counter >= 1345)
            {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#00001A"));
                canvas.drawRect(grass, NightGreen);
                canvas.drawBitmap(house, canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight(), null); 
                canvas.drawBitmap(moon, canvas.getWidth() - 300, 10, null);
                canvas.drawText("You didn't make it before night fall and you were killed", 25, canvas.getHeight()/2  + 100, text);
                canvas.drawText("by the fears of night!", canvas.getWidth()/2 - 200, canvas.getHeight()/2 + 150, text);
            }


            break;

        case 1: 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#00001A"));
            canvas.drawBitmap(moon, (int)MoonX, (int)MoonY, null);
            canvas.drawRect(grass, NightGreen);
            canvas.drawBitmap(houseDude, canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight(), null); 
            canvas.drawBitmap(pause, 0, canvas.getHeight() - pause.getHeight() - 25, null);

            canvas.drawBitmap(Zombie, (int) ZombieX, (int) ZombieY, null);
            if (ZombieX < canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300) ZombieX += 10;
            else 
                {
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#00001A"));
                    canvas.drawRect(grass, NightGreen);

                    canvas.drawText("The monsters got you!", 150, canvas.getHeight()/2  + 100, text);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(house, canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight(), null); 
                    canvas.drawBitmap(moon, canvas.getWidth() - 300, 10, null);
                    ZombieX = canvas.getWidth() + 100;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(play, 0, canvas.getHeight() - play.getHeight() - 25, null);
                }

            if (counter2 < 110) {MoonY --; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 110 && counter2 < 240) {MoonY --; MoonX ++; counter2++;} 
            if (counter2 >= 240 && counter2 < 360) {MoonY -= 0.5; MoonX ++; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 360 && counter2 < 662) {MoonY -= 0.333; MoonX ++; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 662 && counter2 < 1004) {MoonY += 0.333; MoonX++; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 1004 && counter2 < 1104) {MoonY += 0.5; MoonX++; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 1104 && counter2 < 1224) {MoonY ++; MoonX++; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 1224 && counter2 < 1345) {MoonY ++; counter2++;}
            if (counter2 >= 1345)
            {
                canvas.drawText("You killed " + Integer.toString(ZombiesKilled) + " Monsters!", canvas.getWidth()/2 - 100, canvas.getHeight()/2  + 100, text);
                ZombieX = canvas.getWidth() + 100;
                SunX = canvas.getWidth()/2 - sun.getWidth()/2;
                SunY = canvas.getHeight();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
                canvas.drawBitmap(sun, canvas.getWidth()/2, 0, null);
                canvas.drawRect(grass, DayGreen);
                canvas.drawBitmap(houseDude, canvas.getWidth()/2 + 300, canvas.getHeight()/2 - house.getHeight(), null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(play, 0, canvas.getHeight() - play.getHeight() - 25, null);
    }


            break;
        }
        canvas.drawText("Score " + Integer.toString(Score), 0, 10, white);      
        canvas.drawRect(AndroidDudeHitbox, clear);
        canvas.drawRect(DoorHitbox, clear);


        if (AndroidX > canvas.getWidth() || AndroidX < 0 || AndroidY > canvas.getHeight() || AndroidY < 0) {AndroidX = 30; AndroidY = canvas.getHeight()/2;} 

        if (DoorHitbox.contains((int) AndroidX, (int) AndroidY)) possition = 1;
        }
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no, no. Don't ever delay inside `onDraw`. Don't put any game logic in `onDraw`. Just draw. The reason you have a black screen is that `onDraw` is not returning to give the system a chance to put all your drawing onto the physical screen.

Instead, create a completely separate thread that controls game logic (including timing). It can post events or runnables to a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to update the game display.

See the article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for an introduction to this important issue.

Comment: could you go to this question and finish answeering my question? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904287/using-a-thread-as-a-gameloop